# Adding navigation controller to custom made table view

Tags: objective-c, controller, navigation, tableview

I want my table to show up only half way from the bottom of the screen, the upper half meant for an image. To do this, I added a table view through code using CGRectMake specifying the (x,y) co-ordinates I wanted it to start at.

Now, I want each row of this table to navigate to a new view. How do I make the navigation controller push my new view? I tried to add a navigation controller to my main view, but that its helping any.

Please advise on the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [UITableView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), specifically the methods under the header **Managing Selections**:

The method you most likely want is `– selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:`. You can push a view controller onto the stack from this method based on the selected row. To push onto the stack, you will need to set up the `UINavigationController`, then call

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Apple has [a nice tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageSelections/ManageSelections.html) on this topic, complete with many examples.

Comment: Thanks PengOne....I'm doing the exact thing, but I don't see the pushViewController doing anything. So maybe I'm not doing the correct thing to "setup the UINavigationController". Can you help me with details regarding setup Navigation Controller? I added navigation controller to my view already via self.window addSubView:navigationController.view.

Comment: @user1091822 If pushing the view controller does nothing, then there is probably no navigation controller set up.